# Subdomain not pointing to IP despite correct A record

Tags: dns-zone, a-record, dns-server

Let me explain. I have a domain name which is example.com and a subdomain drive.example.com

example.com points to 203.0.113.55 -> no problem

drive.example.com points to nothing according to DNS checker.

My A record is drive.example.com  TTL=14400 IP=203.0.113.55

Furthermore... when I try adding a name instead of an A record I get a "CNAME and other data" conflict

Now.. why would that be??? How can I trouble shoot that?

Comment: What software gives you that error message? Also, where do you host your domain?

Comment: In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: Hi bob. Many thanks. The domain is drive.gsdgrouo.ca. Same thing is happening for www.static.gsdgroup.ca. i am using WHM but my domain don't resolve when using dnschecker however I did include an A record pointing to the IP.

Comment: Are you sure your domain is using your WHM server as name server?

Comment: I am using WHM to manage my DNS. my name server is ns1.secureserver.net, ns2.secureserver.net